# Equivalent of request.getRemoteUser() in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

How ca I access request variables (the remote username) in a GWT RPC implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is working with

```
this.getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteUser()
```

in my RPC class that extends `RemoteServiceServlet`.